# How do I Decrypt AES key (“session_key” from request Json) using Client RSA Private key in php

Tags: php, encryption, aes

I have this encrypted authentication request.

```
{
    "data": "3UsYDGma9CiIbhNa3aZZYoC0tPU9Uui1tpkvu33IOKya8UNXpo4mOL2BGTYogYoax7RP2kQzQM+xoUoC",
    "hash_digest": "JboOpg59i7SeR70VSTXpFjephPFvjbINezT0EgTnhsYnW68txyjoBen5LOTEXE3BaZWQ2IR6SCAaBgy0QJQQ2bQ75cP59/z0OfAcBHVTW3DB4YNe2ApNGIFBz3QGRMCS7J5s6/l/hfqEonBdYQz9t2fQamtCamiUK0Plv17OAEY9XEXgAP86qDUEN56X0nGUewIrdK32bT0ljjYdGuhkGv2r4hGOm+rcSF2BH6pJvwTp5B0BuGxNLuzowrzokh6IqhdL0PpHrJbYqrXHLUl306zS16yph0OHkEPydfZ/P3+1YdeJCEAe0SaKEtk2Pl8BpPCgcPCv+gnFtkBcZTga+g==",
    "session_key": "OsSdo+sNV48lJuZB0HD2Fk5wrd0oGbfVixFsaAC6DjKfig6Lw3wFbb54wW1Q4fAbNTr2qMLCXJtKXV6ldYW/z/g24Ly7mE5YvXs3JWeswNQ4zo67Rtx5CZRJNSR149hoNbFmPWVPiBCsq1YAh0vcSdk0NzL0aKp5xR27p57X2mhVACn+edlT9tRIJUFwfSFHHVOPKftpIjIGQxugW8pSHaMQ9EoP4HZQpDntx56mVLD4ygGrK8IQcHRHHOe+a4mA3XenfLA2rsoCAHnKyW5tqwW2MOZB0s51vQ5kEuX/+nSQ30btcjHiuEpzdkSpzBecpm9rN3FFoSjaH03BSQJr2Q=="
}
```

How do I Decrypt AES key (“session_key” from request Json) using Client RSA Private key in php?

My prerequisites are :

```
Cipher Mode : CBC
Padding Type: PKCS5Padding
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried so far to decrypt - please edit your question and add your code. In PHP using OpenSSL you need "openssl_private_decrypt" to decrypt data with the private key. You will need to know what padding was used for encryption. After decryption of the session key the AES CBC-decryption will be done with "openssl_decrypt". As I saw that the data is of length 60 byte I'm doubting that the data was encrypted with AES in CBC mode - that would require a multiple of 16 (blocklength of AES). Additionally, you need to know what initialization vector was used or prepended/appended.

Comment: What's missing is the mode of operation used for the RSA encryption. Without it you can only try the OAEP and PKCS#1 (v1.5) schemes in the function that Michael indicated above.

Comment: Have you got any solution?